# extract element in jsoup in first level, no recursive

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have this html. I need the "li". I use .select("li"), but inside each "li", there may be another "li" but I'm not interested. I only want "li" in first level.
It possible?

```
<div id="id">
    <ul>
        <li>  
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li> ........ </li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
        </li>
        <li> ........ </li>
        <li> ........ </li>
        <li> ........ </li>
        <li> ........ </li>
        <li> ........ </li>
        .
        .
        .
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
Elements documentElements = document.getElementsByTag("id"); //get the div
Element theList= documentElements.get(0); //get the unordered list
Element listItem = theList.child(0); //this is the first list item in that unordered list
```

This answer assumes you've already loaded the HTML and have the JSoup `Document` ready for traversing

Reference:

- [JSoup API Reference](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

Comment: thanks, but what if I had, for example, a "ul" which would ignore.
That is, I want to take only the "li"

Comment: You can use the [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to navigate the DOM. Ultimately, you cannot ignore/not account for the fact that the `ul` is in there @davidad

Answer (score 3):

It's even simpler - use CSS selector like

```
Document.select('div#id > ul > li')
```

When you use ">" you tell that all you want is the first level child of given DOM element. Take a look at this code - https://gist.github.com/wololock/621a42546cac6dd0daa2 You can simply run it as a groovy script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the CSS selector `>` to specify that you want direct children only.

This can be done *relatively* to the element as in the following example:

```
Element div = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<div id="id">...</div>").body();
div.select(">div>ul>li"); // this will return all li under the first ul
```

And from a ul element, retrieving all first level `li`:

```
ul.select(">li");
```

Or in an *absolute* way (cf @Szymon answer):

```
Document.select('div#id > ul > li')
```